# Bootstrap 3 - Section - How to Center Images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Would love to know how to make my images centered not floating to the left. I tried modifying the float attributes but things just go messy. Help please!
I'm using section tags no grid thingy whatsoever.

When I set the float to "none" this happens

[image]

```css
#hover {
  color: rgba(188, 175, 204, 0.9); 
}

h2#testimonials {
  color: #E72635;
}

div#all {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* generic css */
.view {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.view img {
    display: block;
    position: relative
}
.view h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
.view p {
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center
}
.view a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000
}
.view a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}


/*2*/

.view-second img {  
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.view-second .mask { 
    background-color: rgba(12, 19, 27, 0.6); 
    width: 400px;
    padding: 105px;
    height: 450px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-second h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #8F1925;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
}
.view-second p { 
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;
}
.view-second a.info { 
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

/* */

.view-second:hover .mask { 
    opacity:1; 
    transform: translate(-80px, -125px) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-80px, -125px) rotate(45deg);
}                             


.view-second:hover h2,
.view-second:hover p,
.view-second:hover a.info{ 
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 3;
}

img#articlePic {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>The University Digest</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo1.png" />
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/indexObjects.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- Header Container -->
  <div class="container-full" id="headerC">
   <header class="masthead">
      <p id="headerP">The University Digest</p>
      <p id="subheader">The Official Student Publication of Western Mindanao State University</p>
   </header>
  </div>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div id="nav">
  
  <!--  Content Layout -->
  <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
  <section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="rows">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2 class="section-heading">Articles</h2>
     </div>
     <div id="all">
     <div class="view view-second">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/n6eiy5"  class="img-responsive img-full" alt="" id="articlePic"  />
       <div class="mask"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <h2 id="testimonials">Testimonials</h2>
        <p>&ldquo;A description of some sort between these tags. I am so cool ye and awesomely awesome. He was cool.&rdquo;</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
      </div>  
 
      
     <div class="view view-second">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/ikGTbN"  class="img-responsive" alt="" id="articlePic" />
       <div class="mask"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <h2 id="testimonials">Testimonials</h2>
        <p>&ldquo;A description of some sort between these tags. I am so cool ye and awesomely awesome. He was cool.&rdquo;</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
     </div>  

     <div class="view view-second">
        <img src="http://jacobstone.co.uk/Livetesting/guy.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="" id="articlePic" />
       <div class="mask"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <h2 id="testimonials">Testimonials</h2>
        <p>&ldquo;A description of some sort between these tags. I am so cool ye and awesomely awesome. He was cool.&rdquo;</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
     </div>  

     <div class="view view-second">
        <img src="http://jacobstone.co.uk/Livetesting/guy.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="" id="articlePic"/>
       <div class="mask"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <h2 id="testimonials">Testimonials</h2>
        <p>&ldquo;A description of some sort between these tags. I am so cool ye and awesomely awesome. He was cool.&rdquo;</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
     </div>  

     <div class="view view-second">
        <img src="http://jacobstone.co.uk/Livetesting/guy.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="" id="articlePic"/>
       <div class="mask"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <h2 id="testimonials">Testimonials</h2>
        <p>&ldquo;A description of some sort between these tags. I am so cool ye and awesomely awesome. He was cool.&rdquo;</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
     </div> 

     <div class="view view-second">
        <img src="http://jacobstone.co.uk/Livetesting/guy.jpg"  class="img-responsive" alt="" />
       <div class="mask"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <h2 id="testimonials">Testimonials</h2>
        <p>&ldquo;A description of some sort between these tags. I am so cool ye and awesomely awesome. He was cool.&rdquo;</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
       </div>
     </div> 

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make some changes in your css and you can easily get your desired result through the mentioned below css

**CSS**

```
div#all {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}


.view {
    background: url("../images/bgimg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center #FFFFFF;
    border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #E6E6E6;
    cursor: default;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/57astzLq/1/)

Comment: yes of course the float:left need to be removed for that working!

Answer (score 1):

what about the good old `margin: 0 auto;` for centering elements?

Answer (score 1):

okay and what about this, for centering the images?

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

Another possible solution could be the `display: table-cell;` css rule and then with the horizontal/vertical alignment. I'm currently at work and cannot test it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.view {
    background: url("../images/bgimg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center #fff;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```